# Hooking up daytime running lights on my vehicle using relays

Tags: honda, electrical, lights, relay, ridgeline

I am looking to run my 2006 Honda Ridgeline's daytime running lights on 50% power, or close to it, on the accessory wire. When I turn my park lights, head lights, or brights on, I would like them to shut off.

I'm using a basic relay with connections 30,85,86,87,87a. A wire diagram with the back of this relay would be amazing help. I'm not very knowledgeable about car wiring.